# Проблема отрисовки списка React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

При разработке приложения столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Имеется:
Поле

```
<ScrollView>
    {getSchedules}
</ScrollView>
```

Функция getSchedules выглядит следующим образом:

```
 let getSchedules = schedules.map(value =>
    <ScheduleCard key={value.id} item={value}/>
)
```

В самом объекте ScheduleCard тоже есть формирующийся список trails:

```
return (
    <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginHorizontal: 10, marginVertical: 5, alignSelf: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20}}>{item.from}</Text>
            <View style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}><AntDesign name="arrowright" size={22} color="black"/></View>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20}}>{item.to}</Text>
        </View>
        <Grid>
            <Row style={styles.header}>
                <Col size={sizeCol[0]} style={styles.col}>
                    <Text>#</Text>
                </Col>
                <Col size={sizeCol[1]} style={styles.col}>
                    <Text>Время</Text>
                </Col>
                <Col size={sizeCol[2]} style={styles.col}>
                    <Text>Маршрут</Text>
                </Col>
                <Col size={sizeCol[3]} style={styles.col}>
                    <Text>Транспорт</Text>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            {trails}
        </Grid>
    </View>
)
```

При первоначальной отрисовке контент выводится как должно, при повороте экрана тоже, а после возврата появляются разрывы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы контент всегда отображался правильно?

Comment: на НЕ эмуляторе такая же проблема?

Comment: Да, на телефоне также

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась заменой Grid на View